# What is the simplest way to prefix all strings in an array with a "!" (exclamation mark) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, glob, minimatch

I have two variables I use for when I want to either include or exclude system files (using minimatch glob syntax, where the `!` stands for exclusion).

```
var systemFiles = ['node_modules/**/*', '.git/**/*'];
var ignoredSystemFiles = ['!node_modules/**/*', '!.git/**/*'];
```

But this feels a bit redundant. Is there a simple way to turn the `systemFiles` array into the `ignoredSystemFiles` array (i.e.: prefix all items in `systemFiles` with a `!`)?

I know `!systemFiles` does not work, but something as compact as this would be awesome, as it would allow me to eliminate the `ignoredSystemFiles` variable.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this

```
var systemFiles = ['node_modules/**/*', '.git/**/*'];
var ignoredSystemFiles = systemFiles.map(function(el) { return '!' + el } );
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop should do it :

```
var ignoredSystemFiles = new Array(systemFiles.length);
for(var i = 0; i < systemFiles.length; i++) {
    ignoredSystemFiles[i] = '!' + systemFiles[i];
}
```

Or if you use a recent enough browser and don't care about ie < 9;

```
var ignoredSystemFiles = systemFiles.map(function(v) { return '!' + v; })
```

Comment: You could start with `[]` and use `push` to make the loop one a little simpler, too, but this is probably Node, so `map` is fine.

Comment: This more efficient since pre-allocates the array, I guess it wouldn't matter for a small loop like this.

Comment: It’s not more efficient, though. Have you done any benchmarks?

Comment: @minitech it is, in Node land - v8 still doesn't optimize array method calls, this is faster because loops are faster than .map, not because of pre-allocation of a 2 item array. Note: this is completely irrelevant though and I'd use .map for clarity.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I meant “more efficient than `push`”; doesn’t V8 still treat these as sparse arrays, with the associated performance hit?

Comment: treat what as sparse arrays? The fastest array construction method depends highly on array size.

Comment: @minitech: it is node btw. Forgot to mention that. I've added the tag.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Well, the sparse array created by `new Array(systemFiles.length)`. (Or maybe the particular behaviour of creating a sparse array and immediately filling it in sequential order to the end is optimized? Anyways, a jsPerf revealed that more or less all methods were more or less equivalent under more or less all browsers.)

Comment: It's not sparse if you immediately fill it with values now is it :) ?

Comment: @minitech: There are optimizations that modern engines do when you "preallocate" certain arrays where it can be determined by the engine that the types held in the array will all be the same. I'm not sure under what circumstances the optimizations can be truly enjoyed though.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Does that apply here? (Time to go read V8. Sigh.)

Comment: @minitech yes, it applies here.

Comment: @minitech: That's what I don't know. Assuming that the Array will only hold strings, I'd imagine that a contiguous block of memory is created to accommodate all the references needed to hold the strings, but then the strings themselves need allocation, so I doubt it would make that much difference in this case.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Why? It seems like that optimization would always be applied with `push`. Whether it’s applied to the sparse array at that point (it probably is) doesn’t matter, because it’s not an advantage over `push`.

Comment: Oh, I see, it’s the phrasing. To clarify: I’m asking for reasons to prefer filling a preallocated sparse array over pushing repeatedly to an empty one, performance-wise. I don’t think there are any…

Comment: @minitech: Well, again it probably depends on the situation, but say if it was an Array of numbers, I believe preallocating a sparse Array will be faster, as it wouldn't need to continuously reallocate and copy the Array in the loop. However it could also be that the engine will optimize to predetermine the final size of the Array after the loop, and effectively do the preallocation automatically. I read something about this recently. I'll try to find it.

Comment: ...but certainly in this situation, if there is any optimization, it'll never be noticed.